# How to print an certain amount of rows from a read.table in R Studio

Tags: r, extract, rows

```
da=read.table("m-ibm6708.txt",header=T)  #<== Load data with header

#<== Check dimension of the data (row = sample size, col = variables)
###############502 rows, col 1 = date, col 2 = ibm, col 3 = sprtn
#<== Print out the first 6 rows of the data object "da".
printrows <- da[1:6]
printrows
```

The print rows didn't work. I tried a bunch of things. I think it might use cbind. da is a big table, but I only need the first 6 rows displayed.

Comment: You can use the `head` function: `head(da, 6)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As jdharrison said, `head(da,6)` will work - alternatively you can use the indices to print the top 6 rows `da[1:6,]`

When using the indices notation remember it's `[rows,columns]` and you must include the comma if you have a `data.frame` or `matrix` - i.e. `[1:6,]` for the first six rows or `[,1:6]` for the first six columns.

Answer (score 1):

[Looking like more advance selection then->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl6Ek.png)

- **table_name[c(2:6, 9, 120), ]**

***note:*** from 2 to 6 rows | then 9 no: | then 120 no: row. in this way you can select a specific range as well as specific numbers of rows (or columns).

if you want to do this ***for columns*** just put a comma before like  **table_name[ ,c(2:6, 9, 120) ]**  before comma emptly means you selected all rows.